# create bootable ISO from USB flash drive recovery media with imgburn or other tool

Tags: boot, disaster-recovery, disk-image, uefi

I need clean my HDD and partitions but first did a recovery usb drive with the recovery tool, the recovery is one of Thinkpad E431 and was done right.
I cant rely only on a fragile usb drive to keep this copy and want keep a bkp on my external hdd as an bootable .iso file too.
The only software to windows i found to clone usb drives to bootable .iso that works was imgburn but you need put the path to etfsboot.com as "Boot image" to it work. 
My prolem is that the Lenovo tool doesnt create this file inside recovery and cant find a way to config imgburn to create my bootable bkp.

Im not the only one with problems:

http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?/topic/24614-create-bootable-iso-from-usb-flash-drive-recovery-media

http://forum.imgburn.com/index.php?/topic/24193-problem-i-can-not-create-a-uefi-bootable-iso-image/

There is an article with several tools but no one created a valid one:

www.raymond.cc/blog/make-full-backup-of-your-ipod-usb-flash-drive-and-mp3-players-by-imaging/

The content of my recovery pendrive is:

```
=====================
Lenovo Thinkpad E431 Recovery Pendrive
=====================
Z:.
+---efi
¦   +---boot
¦   +---microsoft
¦       +---boot
¦           +---fonts
¦           +---resources
+---boot
¦   +---resources
¦   +---fonts
+---sources
    +---Lenovo
    ¦   +---FACTORY_POST
    ¦   +---FACTORY_PRE
    ¦   +---RESET_POST
    ¦   +---RESET_PRE
    ¦   +---SWDD
    +---recovery
        +---old
=====================
Z:\efi
Z:\bootmgr
Z:\boot
Z:\bootmgr.efi
Z:\sources
Z:\reagent.xml
Z:\efi\boot
Z:\efi\microsoft
Z:\efi\boot\bootx64.efi
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\BCD
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\resources
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\chs_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\cht_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\jpn_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\kor_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\malgunn_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\malgun_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\meiryon_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\meiryo_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\msjhn_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\msjh_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\msyhn_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\msyh_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\segmono_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\segoen_slboot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\segoe_slboot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\fonts\wgl4_boot.ttf
Z:\efi\microsoft\boot\resources\bootres.dll
Z:\boot\BCD
Z:\boot\resources
Z:\boot\boot.sdi
Z:\boot\fonts
Z:\boot\resources\bootres.dll
Z:\boot\fonts\chs_boot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\cht_boot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\jpn_boot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\kor_boot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\malgunn_boot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\malgun_boot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\meiryon_boot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\meiryo_boot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\msjhn_boot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\msjh_boot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\msyhn_boot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\msyh_boot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\segmono_boot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\segoen_slboot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\segoe_slboot.ttf
Z:\boot\fonts\wgl4_boot.ttf
Z:\System Volume Information\IndexerVolumeGuid
Z:\sources\install.swm
Z:\sources\install2.swm
Z:\sources\install3.swm
Z:\sources\install4.swm
Z:\sources\install5.swm
Z:\sources\Lenovo
Z:\sources\PBR.TXT
Z:\sources\PBRALL.TXT
Z:\sources\PBRLABEL.CMD
Z:\sources\ResetConfig.XML
Z:\sources\ResetConfigAll.xml
Z:\sources\SDRIVE.ZIP
Z:\sources\WDRIVE.ZIP
Z:\sources\recovery
Z:\sources\Lenovo\FactoryPost.cmd
Z:\sources\Lenovo\FactoryPre.cmd
Z:\sources\Lenovo\FACTORY_POST
Z:\sources\Lenovo\FACTORY_PRE
Z:\sources\Lenovo\ResetPost.cmd
Z:\sources\Lenovo\ResetPre.cmd
Z:\sources\Lenovo\RESET_POST
Z:\sources\Lenovo\RESET_PRE
Z:\sources\Lenovo\SWDD
Z:\sources\Lenovo\FACTORY_POST\Bwinrebcd.cmd
Z:\sources\Lenovo\FACTORY_POST\fpost.cmd
Z:\sources\Lenovo\FACTORY_POST\LenovoBT.EFI
Z:\sources\Lenovo\FACTORY_PRE\fpre.cmd
Z:\sources\Lenovo\RESET_POST\rpost.cmd
Z:\sources\Lenovo\RESET_PRE\rpre.cmd
Z:\sources\Lenovo\SWDD\CPP2SWDD.SCP
Z:\sources\Lenovo\SWDD\RMLTSWDD.CMD
Z:\sources\Lenovo\SWDD\SWWORKSWDD.lst
Z:\sources\recovery\old
=====================
```

Comment: Have you tried USB Image tool http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/create-image-usb-drive/ or ImageUSB http://usb-image-tool.en.uptodown.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Last time when I need to create my own bootable Mac OS X USB drives for data recovery I used recovery software. I found detailed instruction here https://www.cleverfiles.com/boot-mac-from-usb.html. Then I just connected an extra storage device to my Mac, ran Disk Drill and chose the "Create Boot Drive" option.

Comment: You could greatly improve this answer by adding the essential information from the link to the post.